# Clicking back page invokes get or post request?

Tags: python, bottle

Im using my below code to display a page..This page startpage is called from the Login page. When the user post username and password it correctly calls the POST request..

Now, if I navigate to this startpage from some other page through back or front button, what method will get executed "GET" or "POST"?

```
@app.route('/StartPage',method='GET')
def test():
    print 'In get'

@app.route('/StartPage',method='POST')
def retrieve():

   username = request.forms.get('username')
   password = request.forms.get('password')

   return template('LoginPage')
```

This is written in Bottle framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using back and forward, typically your browser will replay the same type of request that was originally made, so if the user was trying to login to `StartPage` with a `POST` request and given username and password, that `POST` request would be sent again with the same username and password.

If they originally accessed `StartPage` with a `GET` request and didn't provide a username and password, that `GET` request will be sent again upon using the back/forward commands. This should generally hold true across basic HTTP frameworks.

Comment: This has led to the common idiom of [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), to mitigate somewhat the case of users sending unintentional duplicate POST requests.

Comment: @natdempk: Thanks for the clarification..The page Im looking says "The code on this page disabled back and forward caching"..Does it mean that the POST or GET request will be disabled??

Comment: @user1050619 I believe that means that the `POST` or `GET` requests will always be sent when the back/forward buttons are used and that the browsers cached version of the page will never be used.

Comment: @natdempk: Thanks..Its confusing...When I click back button the page gets loaded with a response code of 304 but I don't see it entered the server as it does not print the print statement that I had given in the POST request..Any thoughts?/

Comment: @user1050619 a `304` response means that the page hasn't changed since last requested and that the web browser is going to use the cached version instead, so my guess is that back and forward caching are not actually disabled.

Comment: @natdempk:..Yes, makes sense...My only concern is that, if the call is made to the server on hitting the back button..then I should see the print statement given there, correct?..Why im not seeing it?

Comment: @user1050619 No, the request is made to the server, but the page is not actually re-rendered on the server. The server just tells the browser to use the version it already has as it is up to date, so the print statement is never called.

Comment: @Natdempk:Assume that page gets some rows from db..so, if some rows have changed in db...then there should be a change in what is displayed..so, how server can make a decision without actually querying that information..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52121/discussion-between-natdempk-and-user1050619)